# How to read config to a map with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have a service that works with the config server and pulls configuration files from there.
An example of simplified part of a configuration file:

```
car:
    #name of Map
    model:
        volkswagen:
            year: 1937
            ranking: 2
            office:
                country: germany
                city: wolfsburg
            
        honda:
            year: 1948
            ranking: 3
            office:
                country: japan
                city: tokyo
    #common parameters for all models
    wheels: 4
    #etc...
```

How can I read this to a Map?

I tried:

```
public class Office
{
    private String country;
    
    private String city;
    
    //setters and getters
}
```

```
public class CarModel
{
    private Office office;
    
    private String year;
    
    private int ranking;

    //setters and getters
}
```

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "car")
public class Car
{
    private Map<String, CarModel> model = new HashMap<>();
    
    private int wheels;
    //other common fields and setters and getters for them
    
    
    public Map<String, CarModel> getModel()
    {
        return model;
    }
}
```

When I inject `Car` into my @Service class and try to use, all common fields(`wheels` and etc) has values, `year` and `ranking` also has values for each key in map, **but `office` has null value**. How can I fix it without modifying the structure of the yaml file and without manually reading the config using Environment?

Answer (score 2):

Guess, you should seek an error elsewhere. I replicated your classes and props:
https://github.com/ILyaCyclone/stackoverflow-read-map-76146293

And it works fine for me:

`Car{model={volkswagen=CarModel{office=Office{country='germany', city='wolfsburg'}, year='1937', ranking=2}, honda=CarModel{office=Office{country='japan', city='tokyo'}, year='1948', ranking=3}}, wheels=4}`

Just a few notes:

1. You `Car` class should be `@ConfigurationProperties` and not `@Configuration`. Don't forget @EnableConfigurationProperties (depending on your Spring Boot version). I would suggest naming this class `CarProperties`.
2. `private Map<String, CarModel> model = new HashMap<>();` - no need to create an instance, this will be done by Spring.

And these notes should not lead to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using ObjectMapper as below

```
// Loading the YAML file from the /resources folder
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("config.yaml").getFile());

// Instantiating a new ObjectMapper as a YAMLFactory
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());

// Mapping the employee from the YAML file to the Employee class
CarModel carModel = om.readValue(file, CarModel.class);
```

hope this will help